# Classical piece performed on hammer organ

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

Could you please help me identify the composer and the name of the following tune? I have no idea where to start searching for it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2MF9Nhw0ng

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I asked the author of the video (look at the YouTube comments) and they say it's an improvisation, sorry.

Comment: @AlvaroFuentes You should turn that into an answer!

Comment: Yeah.suggest you turn that into an answer. It is quite common for the organist to play a mixture of improvisations plus known pieces before a church service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an original improvisation by the creator of this video, Brita falch Leutert.

Source: I asked the author of the video (look at the YouTube comments).